# How to get textbox values to jquery variable and make popup confirmation?

Tags: jquery, html

I have  tried to get textbox values to popup confirmation...

But it is not working

Help me pls...

```js
function myfunction() {
  
  var first = $('input[name=firstname]').val();
  var last = $('input[name=lastname]').val();
  
  alert(first); // Shows alert
  
  //But here i need to get all the text box values and display it in the popup box
  
  // After confirmation(OK) the form will submmit to second page 
  
  // Incase of cancel it returns to the form
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="second.html" method="post" onsubmit="myfunction()">
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname">
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: Do you mean combining `first` and `last`?

Comment: What, exactly, do you need help with?

Comment: @PeterKA Read the comments in the code

Comment: While submit the form it need to ask confirmation with the all field values... If clicked NO in confirmation it should return to the form if YES means should submit the form

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you remove the inline submit handler and do this instead.
Please note you cannot POST to .html

```js
$(function() { // on page load
  $("#formId").on("submit", function(e) { // assign submi handler
    var first = $('input[name=firstname]').val();
    if (first == "") { // test first name
      alert("Please enter first name");
      return false;
    }
    var last = $('input[name=lastname]').val();
    if (last == "") {
      alert("Please enter last name");
      return false;
    }
    // Confirm (could be a proper dialog)
    if (!confirm("You entered\n"+first+" "+last+".\ncorrect ? ")) {
      return false; // cancel submit if not confirmed
    }
    // here the form is allowed to be submitted to second.html
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formId" action="second.html" method="post">
  First Name:
  <input type="text" name="firstname">Last name:
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You must change with this

```
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="myfunction()">
```

Plus: If you use id for form elements, it will be better than name.

Comment: What is wrong with `<form>`'s `onsubmit`? Except the fact that it is outdated inline JS.

Answer (score -1):

Tou want something like this.

```js
function myfunction() {
  
  var first = $('input[name=firstname]').val();
  var last = $('input[name=lastname]').val();
  
  if ( confirm(first + " " + last) ){
      alert("submit to second.html");
  }else {
      alert("cancel submiting");
      return false;
  }  
       
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="second.html" method="post" onsubmit="myfunction()">
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname">
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: This will submit the form regardless of answer to the confirm

Comment: It is just alert.. But i need confirmation

Comment: Yes, the code on the if should be adapted, you obviuously don't want to show an alert after a confirm box.

Comment: @Kevin confirm return `true` if the OK button is clicked, that's why I put it on an if statement, where is the first alert you should submit your form, and on the second cancel the submition (`preventDefault` or `return false` for example)